# min-height and height not working

Tags: html, css

Why has the div not `height:100%`   ?

http://jsfiddle.net/28V6q/2/

I need the body not to have a fixed height due to jquery ui draggable

```
html {
    height:100%;
}

body {
    min-height:100%;
    margin:0;
}

div {
    height:100%;
    background:red;
}

<body>
    <div>asdf</div>
</body>
```

Comment: I understand your want to keep your min height on body. But answers below are constructive so why do you vote it down ?

Comment: are you allowed to add `position: absolute;` to the div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer would be: If the parent's height is not set explicitly, the child height will be set to auto.

This article explains why what you are trying to achieve isn't working: http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201306/height_in_percent_when_parent_has_min-height_and_no_height/

This is from the CSS 2.1 specification (which, as far as I know, doesn't differ from CSS3)

> The percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the
>   generated box’s containing block. If the height of the containing
>   block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content
>   height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, the value
>   computes to ‘auto’.

The solution would then either be to set `position:absolute;` on the **div** or `height:100%;` on the **body**.

Answer (score 0):

You should apply `height: 100%` to body rather that `min-height: 100%`

An example : http://jsfiddle.net/28V6q/3/